# Trivial zeroes of Zeta are simple

Tags: riemann-zeta

The trivial zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function are located on $-2\mathbb N^*$ and they are simple. It is not difficult to see that, but the proof I have in mind is using the fact that $\xi(-2k)=\xi(1+2k)>0$ for $k\ge 1$ integer.

Well, it is not so simple, since it is using (part of) the functional equation for $\xi$, definitely  not an elementary fact. Is there a simpler proof of the assertion in the title?

Comment: Here you can find a simple proof of this fact (Page 3, Lemma 3) http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/comp_analysis/note-zeta2.pdf

Comment: Rudely simulposted to MO, without notice to either site. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215840/trivial-zeroes-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-are-simple

Answer (score 1):

A priori, the Riemann zeta function only makes sense for $\text{Re} (s) > 1$. Most commonly, one understands the zeta function for $\text{Re} (s) < 0$ through some sort of functional equation. One does not need the reflecting functional equation $\xi(s) = \xi(1-s)$. Riemann's original functional equation
$$ \zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\pi s/2) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)$$
is sufficient. Another common functional equation is
$$ \zeta(s) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty  \frac{x^s}{e^x - 1} \frac{dx}{x},$$
which highlights the relationship between the Bernouilli numbers and the zeta function. This functional equation (with some consideration of the zeroes and poles involved) is mentioned [in Daniel Fischer's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/856187/9754).

Of course, there are very many ways to meromorphically continue the zeta function. One would expect most of the good ways to all illustrate the locations of the zeroes.