# About the functional equation between $\zeta$ and $\Gamma$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, functional-equations, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

It is well-known applying the monotone convergence theorem that for all $x>1$ we have the following functional equation : $\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)= \displaystyle \int \limits_{[0,+\infty]} \dfrac{t^{x-1}}{\exp(t)-1}\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)$ or $\zeta(x)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\displaystyle \int \limits_{[0,+\infty]} \dfrac{t^{x-1}}{\exp(t)-1}\mathrm{d}\lambda(t) \ $ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue's measure).

Recall that : $\Gamma(x) = \displaystyle \int \limits_{[0,+\infty]}\exp(-t)t^{x-1}\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)$ and $\zeta(x)= \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^x}$ and are well-defined for all $x>1$.

Is it possible to find a link between this functional equation and Bernoulli's numbers ?

I was thinking about the following result (which is not trivial) : $\dfrac{t}{\exp(t)-1} = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}B_n \dfrac{t^n}{n!} \ $ where the sequence $(B_n)_{n\ge 0}$ represents the Bernoulli's numbers.

Then we will obtain for all $x > 1$ : $\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)= \displaystyle \int \limits_{[0,1]}t^{x-2}\left( \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}B_n \dfrac{t^n}{n!} \right) \mathrm{d}\lambda(t) + \displaystyle \int \limits_{[1,+\infty]} \dfrac{t^{x-1}}{\exp(t)-1} \mathrm{d}\lambda(t) \\ = \displaystyle \int \limits_{[0,1]}\left( \displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}B_n \dfrac{t^{n+x-2}}{n!} \right) \mathrm{d}\lambda(t) + \displaystyle \int \limits_{[1,+\infty]} \dfrac{t^{x-1}}{\exp(t)-1} \mathrm{d}\lambda(t) \\ = \displaystyle\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{B_n}{n!(n+x-1)} + \displaystyle \int \limits_{[1,+\infty]} \dfrac{t^{x-1}}{\exp(t)-1} \mathrm{d}\lambda(t)$

The last equality is obtained using the fact that the series converges uniformly on every compact set included in $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$.

I doubt that we could  go further ?

Thnaks in advance !

Comment: The values $\zeta(-n)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ are definitely related to Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: I suspect it will be difficult as the Mellin transform of $t^{n-1}$ is a distribution: $\mathcal{M}_t\left[t^{n-1}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty t^{n-1}\,t^{s-1}\,dt=2 \pi  \delta (i\,(s+n-1))$.

Comment: @StevenClark thank you but could you be more explicit ?

Comment: With respect to my first comment, I believe the answer I posted on MathOverflow at https://mathoverflow.net/q/294849 provides some insight, but the question here seems to overlap the question and answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855740 which perhaps provides insight more relevant to your question.

Comment: @StevenClark Thank you for clarifications and for the second link !

Comment: $t/(e^t-1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n t^n/n!$ holds only when $|t|<2\pi$, so it's nonsense to use this for $t\in(0,+\infty)$; and even if this series converged *everywhere*, what would you expect to get by integrating it *over* $(0,+\infty)$?..

Comment: @metamorphy Indeed that's why a reasonable thing is to cut the integral into two parts with $[0,1]$ and $[1,+\infty)$ and then we just have the Bernoulli numbers in the first part ! I just wanted a functional equation which would  make appear these three well-knows objects nothing more !

Answer (score 1):

My own opinion, but still worth posting as an answer, not a comment. The [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) $$\zeta(-n)=(-1)^n\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1},\qquad\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}B_{2n}\qquad(n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant0})$$ look like a complete story (along the lines of the question).

With [Riemann's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann%27s_functional_equation) at hand, each one is a consequence of the other; so it's the connection to the (*definition* of) Bernoulli numbers that deserves a discussion (although I'm sure it's done in a number of other questions here on MSE).

Taking the generating function $z/(e^z-1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n z^n/n!$ as the definition, the second of the identities is obtained from $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\zeta(2n)z^{2n}=\sum_{k,n=1}^\infty\left(\frac zk\right)^{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^2}{k^2-z^2}=\frac12(1-\pi z\cot\pi z)$$ using a [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Partial_fraction_expansion) consequence of the infinite product for the sine function, and then the complex-exponential form of $\cot\pi z$, making a *direct* link to the definition of Bernoulli numbers as stated.

An alternative way to get the *first* of the identities above (i.e., not via the functional equation) is to play [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) back, starting with (your well-known representation) $$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}\,dx}{e^x-1}.$$